# Datatables select and search filter

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using data table from [here](https://datatables.net/). I have implemented column wise select filter. I would like to implement a mixed of select and search filter for my table. In other words, say I have 3 rows : `No`, `Name`, `Address`. The `No` column should have a search filter. The `Name` should have a select filter and the `Address` should have a search filter. How can I achieve this? Any sample code can help to modify it to my real application.

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve it ?

Comment: you are looking for this..https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this utilizing the [Column Filter plugin](https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html)

```
('#example').dataTable().columnFilter({
    aoColumns: [ 
                { type: "text" },
                { type: "select", values: [ 'Adam', 'Bob', 'Casey', 'Dave']  },
                { type: "text" }
            ]
```

This sets up a filter for each column. The first column will be text, second a drop down containing the names listed in `values` and the third another text box.

If you want your `No` column to be a [numeric range](https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/numberRange.html), you can do this instead:

```
{ type: "number-range" }
```

If you just want to search a single number, you can make it:

```
{ type: "number" }
```

Comment: one small ques, that values of 'adam', 'bob' and other can be made to fetch from db?